# Creating an Eclipse plug-in with its own folder structure

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I want to develop an [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) plug-in with my own project structure. So in detail, where can I define the folders which should be created when creating my own project after installing the plugin?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of how one would create a bare bones project with two folders:

```
    IProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
    IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
    IProject project = root.getProject("MyProject");
    try {
        project.create(progressMonitor);
        project.open(progressMonitor);
        IFolder firstFolder = project.getFolder("firstfolder");
        firstFolder.create(true, true, progressMonitor);
        IFolder secondFolder = project.getFolder("secondfolder");
        secondFolder.create(true, true, progressMonitor);           
    } catch (CoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You can modify this code to suit your needs and execute it from your "New Project" wizard.

Mind you, the code I posted is just an example, I strongly suggest you look at [Workspace and Resource API](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/The_Official_Eclipse_FAQs#Workspace_and_Resources_API) to learn more about this topic, find out how you can add your own project nature and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will check it out as soon as possible!